# How can I chain together SELECT EXISTS() queries?

Tags: mysql, exists, chaining

I have this simple query

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT a FROM A WHERE a = 'lorem ipsum');
```

That will return a 0 or 1 if there exists a row in A that contains 'lorem ipsum'

I would like to chain this behavior together. So I would get multiple rows, each with a 0 or 1 if that value exists.

How would I go about doing this?

Update:

It's possible to do it like this but then I get a column for each result.

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT a FROM A WHERE a = 'lorem ipsum'), EXISTS(SELECT a FROM A WHERE a = 'dolor sit');
```

Comment: It's 8:30 in the morning, I'm allowed to misspell exists :)

Comment: Could You add an example of an A table and a desired result of a query?

Comment: I think I have the answer from Martin, thanks though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT a FROM A WHERE a = 'lorem ipsum')
UNION ALL
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT a FROM A WHERE a = 'dolor sit');
```

Or

```
SELECT EXISTS(SELECT a FROM A WHERE A.a = T.a)
FROM (SELECT 'lorem ipsum' AS a 
      UNION ALL 
      SELECT 'dolor sit') T
```

Comment: I keep getting strange errors for the 2nd example but the first one looks good. Wondering how efficient UNION ALL vs the solution I have in my answer (if I could use it)

Comment: The error: "Illegal mix of collations (latin1_swedish_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_general_ci,COERCIBLE) for operation '='" Probably since the table created is not the same collation as the table A.

Comment: Can you try adding an explicit `Collate` clause? `COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci`. In Microsoft SQL Server you could put it as `WHERE A.a = T.a COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci` Not sure if the syntax and placement in MySQL is the same.

Comment: [looks like that should work](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html)

Comment: I got the 2nd query working and it's very slow. About 3,1 seconds when the first query was a fraction of a second.

Comment: Accepting due to the 1st suggestion, the 2nd one is slower.

Comment: Syntactically those are the only 2 ways I can think of doing it. Only dabble in MySQL myself so not sure if anything can be done to improve the performance of the 2nd version. The only thing I can think though is that maybe the explicit `collate` is preventing use of an index. Maybe the forced collation needs to be the other way round or the collate clause needs to be pushed down into the derived table definition (these are just guesses though)

Comment: I had to turn the collation around, force the A table into utf8. Probably the conversion that slows it down. The UNION ALL version is currently running 0.0017 seconds which is fine for now :)

Answer (score 0):

Don't have an SQL server handy, but try this:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
UNION ALL
SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS (...) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this.

```
    SELECT
        CASE
            WHEN a = 'lorem ipsum' THEN 1
            WHEN a = 'dolor sit' THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS something
    FROM A;
```

Comment: This will select the whole table, and not only the result in the query.